# Uncontrolled reputation loss

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

From yesterday I have lost reputation points (I don't know exactly, because I'm not recording it, but I got > 200 two days in a row and right now it's < 200).

There is also nothing in the reputation tab, no negative points. It's as if I never had them. What happened and is this recoverable?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @Stijn yes, here I have "earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days" whereas lately I got mortarboard badge, where would I get it from?

Comment: Could be that someone retracted their upvote on a post of yours. The badge won't be taken away once awarded.

Comment: I would get a notification if I lost it. Also would I loose reputation on at least two separate days?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you would get a notification?

Comment: No, not 100%. I just noticed, that revoking upvote or marking answer as correct does that. I don't know if always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have deleted some negatively scoring answers, however, in some cases the reputation loss from the down-votes wasn't enough to counter the reputation gain from previous up-votes. This means that when you deleted the post you lost reputation.

However, neither today (7th March) nor yesterday (6th March) did you earn 200+ reputation.

You did earn 210 on the 5th and 205 on the 4th March.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand the first statement. Does it mean, that deleting downvoted answers does make me loose reputation anyway?

Comment: @Andronicus upvotes give more reputation than downvotes take away, so when you delete an answer (within a certain time frame) with 5 upvotes and 6 downvotes, you will actually lose reputation.

Comment: @Andronicus it depends on the voting. If your answer has 1 up-vote and 2 down-votes the score will be -1 but you'll have 10 - 2 - 2 = +6 reputation points from that answer. Deleting it will therefore lose you 6 points.

Comment: Ok I get it now. I just thought, I deleted posts that got only downvotes. But why now? I got the badge although I shouldn't have. Does that mean, that if I looked here https://stackoverflow.com/reputation yesterday there wouldn't be any score > 200?

Comment: @Andronicus as Stijn said on your question: the badge won't be redacted once awarded.

Comment: Yes, but my question is why did I get it in the first place?

Comment: @Andronicus because at the end of the UTC day on March 4th and March 5th you had +200 in each day.  If stuff gets deleted after the fact, that won't remove the badge.